# External library reference works in Webpack but not in JSPM within Aurelia

Tags: javascript, datatable, aurelia, jspm

I am trying to use the Datatables.net library in my Aurelia application.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables.net

The issue is that the following code works with the Webpack version of Aurelia. The JSPM build I get the error

> mytable.js:13 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function(…)attached @ mytable.js:13attached @ aurelia-templating.js:2947attached @ aurelia-templating.js:1016attached @ aurelia-templating.js:1472attached @ aurelia-templating.js:1026attached @ aurelia-templating.js:1472(anonymous function) @ aurelia-framework.js:204

I added       `"datatables.net": "npm:datatables.net@^1.10.11",` to my package.json and did `jspm install -y` and datatables.net was said it was installed.

ViewModel:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import dataTable from 'datatables.net';
export class MyTable{
  dataSet = [
      ['Ken','Husband','Home'],
      ['Barbie','Wife','Home']
    ];
  attached(){

    //console.log(dataTable);
    var dataSet = this.dataSet;
    //console.log(dataSet);
    //require( 'datatables.net' )( window, $ );
    $(() =>     $('#example').DataTable({ 
        select: true,
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Position" },
        { title: "Office" }

        ]
    }) );
  }
 }
```

View

```
<template>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div>test datatables</div>
    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
  </div>

</template>
```

Comment: its entirely possible jspm is failing to import it properly. Sometimes you have to add shims or specify its main entry point.

Comment: @MeirionHughes how would I go about doing that? Not sure what a Shim is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue. It was all in how I was adding the libraries to my project, how I was importing them, and a slight issue with the way JSPM loads the library (at least I think someone with more experience with Javascript can correct me).

The solution is at this link.

https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/473

A working example:

Add the following libraries to your project

```
jspm install datatables.net=npm:datatables.net
jspm install datatables.net-responsive=npm:datatables.net-responsive
jspm install datatables.net-responsive-bs=npm:datatables.net-responsive-bs
jspm install datatables.net-bs=npm:datatables.net-bs
```

Index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aurelia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jspm_packages/npm/font-awesome@4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body aurelia-app="main">
    <div class="splash">
      <div class="message">Aurelia Navigation Skeleton</div>
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>

    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
      // ensure jQuery is loaded and set before other imports in you project
      System.import('jquery')
        .then(jquery => {
          window.jQuery = jquery;
          window.$ = jquery;

          // now load and bootstrap aurelia
          return System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

welcome.html:

```
<template>
  <section class="au-animate">
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px">
      <div>test datatables</div>
      <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%"></table>
    </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

welcome.js

```
import * as datatable from 'datatables';
//following only once in you app i think
import * as responsive from 'datatables.net-responsive';
import * as responsiveBs from 'datatables.net-responsive-bs';
import * as netBs from 'datatables.net-bs';

//This could be done an alternative way apparently (see below) but this is what worked for me. I have to give credit to the poster doktordirk on the github aurelia issue.
responsive.default(window, $)
responsiveBs.default(window, $)    
netBs.default(window, $)

//alternative method
//let responsive = responsive.default(); // to change settings?
//responsiveBs.default();
//netBs.default();

export class Welcome {
  dataSet = [
      ['Ken','Husband','Home'],
      ['Barbie','Wife','Home']
    ];

  attached() {
   // can call: responsive(settings, options);
    $('#example').DataTable({
       select: true,
       data: this.dataSet,
       columns: [
         { title: "Name" },
         { title: "Position" },
         { title: "Office" }
        ]
   });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using jspm you don't need to change anything in package.json. You should install javascript libraries using jspm, like this:

```
jspm install npm:datatables.net
```

Then, you have to import it, using this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'datatables.net';
export class MyTable{
  dataSet = [
      ['Ken','Husband','Home'],
      ['Barbie','Wife','Home']
    ];
  attached(){

    //console.log(dataTable);
    var dataSet = this.dataSet;
    $('#example').DataTable({ 
        select: true,
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Position" },
        { title: "Office" }

        ]
    });
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but I am getting the same issue. I cleared the entire skeleton and did it again and it still gives me mytable.js:15 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function(…)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the method is down-case. Try `$(...).dataTable`

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the same issue with "DataTables" or "dataTables".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it has already been setup in jspm: https://github.com/jspm/registry/blob/master/package-overrides/github/DataTables/DataTables@1.10.4.json

Simply install it via its alias:

`jspm install datatables`

Responsive has overrides too: and https://github.com/jspm/registry/blob/master/package-overrides/github/DataTables/Responsive@1.0.4.json

but I think you'll have to install it like:

`jspm install github:DataTables/Responsive@1.0.4`

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to get this example to work (https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html).  which needs several other libraries. The datatables link you provided will work but I end up in the same place as I am now with those libraries (as they aren't in jspm). I have been trying to get datatables.net to work so I could repeat the process with the other libraries I am needing to make this example work. I can get the regular "datatables" to work but NOT "datatables.net". If I use "datatables", when I need the other dependencies, I'm in the same boat.

Comment: Thanks. So I added both of those and looking at what it downloaded I am still missing 1 js file dependency. With `jspm install datatables` I get the `jquery.dataTables.js`, `jspm install github:DataTables/Responsive` gives me `dataTables.responsive.js` and `responsive.bootstrap.js`, but I am still missing `dataTables.bootstrap.js` and digging through those links I don't see anywhere an override has been done for `dataTables.bootstrap.js`. Am I just out of luck for that one? Without it, I don't think that example I linked will work.

Comment: Yeah I suspect you'll need to do some overrides for it (or datatables.net if that is easier). jspm is still being developed. I think the new 0.17 version (still beta) has some improvements for npm module loading.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some information on how to create the overrides?

Comment: I found the solution where I don't have to use the overrides. See my posted answer.